# How to normalize the features extracted from Kinect C#?

Tags: c#, kinect, normalization

I'm doing a project to extract the lip features with a Kinect in C#. My question is how to do a normalization with the features?

I think I have to do a function like this:

Nd = ( Cd * Fd ) / dFN

where Nd is the normalized distance, Cd is the current distance to the Kinect, Fd is the depth value of the forehead which every frame is normalized and dFN is the depth value for which every frame is normalized.

Also, a z-score normalization must be implemented:

z = (X - μ) / σ

where z is the result of the z-score normalization, X is the current feature value, μ is the mean obtained in one database and σ represents the variance.

How can I do this normalization based on the features?

Here is the function where I receive the features to normalize:

```cs
private void FaceReader_FrameArrived(object sender, HighDefinitionFaceFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    NewRecording();

    using (var frame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
    {
        if (frame != null)
        {
            frame.GetAndRefreshFaceAlignmentResult(_faceAlignment);
            UpdateFacePoints();

            var vertices = _faceModel.CalculateVerticesForAlignment(_faceAlignment);

            var lipLeftCorner = vertices[(int)HighDetailFacePoints.MouthLeftcorner];
            var lipRightCorner = vertices[(int)HighDetailFacePoints.MouthRightcorner];
            var lipWidth = Math.Abs(lipRightCorner.X - lipLeftCorner.X);
            var lipTopCorner = vertices[(int)HighDetailFacePoints.MouthUpperlipMidtop];
            var lipBottomCorner = vertices[(int)HighDetailFacePoints.MouthLowerlipMidbottom];
            var lipHeight = Math.Abs(lipTopCorner.Y - lipBottomCorner.Y);
            var chinCenter = vertices[(int)HighDetailFacePoints.ChinCenter];

            Console.WriteLine(lipLeftCorner.X.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(lipRightCorner.X.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(lipWidth.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(lipTopCorner.Y.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(lipBottomCorner.Y.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(lipHeight.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(lipTopCorner.Z.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(chinCenter.X.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(chinCenter.Y.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```